# Why connection between phpmyadmin and mysql docker container doesn't work

Tags: mysql, linux, docker, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to connect a phpmyadmin-container to a mysql-container to view the databases. phpmyadmin web interface return error `Cannot log in to the MySQL server` with `mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No route to host`.
What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

I use this operations:

1. `docker-compose down && docker-compose up -d`
2. Type to web browser http://localhost:8080
3. I use login as user `root`, password `test`
4. Get error described above

My **docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    links:
      - db
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [official guide](https://hub.docker.com/r/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/):

You need to specify some environment in order to link to an external mysql container:

**Environment variables summary**

```
PMA_ARBITRARY - when set to 1 connection to the arbitrary server will be allowed
PMA_HOST - define address/host name of the MySQL server
PMA_VERBOSE - define verbose name of the MySQL server
PMA_PORT - define port of the MySQL server
PMA_HOSTS - define comma separated list of address/host names of the MySQL servers
PMA_VERBOSES - define comma separated list of verbose names of the MySQL servers
PMA_PORTS - define comma separated list of ports of the MySQL servers
PMA_USER and PMA_PASSWORD - define username to use for config authentication method
PMA_ABSOLUTE_URI - define user-facing URI
```

For you, the mysql name is `db`, so you need to do next:

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    environment:
      PMA_HOSTS: db
```

Also, `--link` depracated, just delete it, `docker-compose` will set network for you automatically to let the containers see each other with dns help.

Comment: I'm trying your examle and it doesn't work for me. So I append `PMA_PORTS: 8080` and still it doesn't work.As far as I understand "Environment variables summary", there is no need to set other variables in this example.

Comment: Try to add `command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password` to mysql service to change default auth, see update answer. Remember delete `--link` and also not add other things until you know what you are adding, first try the example without modify anything. And also first do `docker-compose down` before `docker-compose up`.

Comment: What this means
PMA_ARBITRARY - when set to 1 connection to the arbitrary server will be allowed?

Comment: YES. You will have a new entry in the login page to input any server if set to 1, which will not limit to the servers you defined in `PMA_HOSTS`. But unlike in physical environment which use `$cfg['AllowArbitraryServer']`, in docker environment, you still need to assure the target server is in the same network of phpmyadmin, e.g. all services' name in the same dockerfile with default docker network which could visit eachother.